# HTTP or websockets?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have a project which needs live updates on certain parts of the website, this done with websockets. On other parts of the site I use POST/GET. I just came to think of it, is there any reasons not to use only  websockets? What could I gain/loose by dropping POST/GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser support for Web Sockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) is good in *current* versions. But the answer very much depends on your project.

You'll have to manage the websocket, in case it closes unexpectedly. A GET/POST is easier in that regard. You can just set an interval and if one goes missing, there's always the next request.

If it's not a critical feature, and if your audience is skewed towards chrome/firefox/safari, and your websocket implementation is solid already, i'd drop GET/POST.

Comment: I'd like to think my implementation is well-made and well-functioning, though my next goal is to compliment it with a fallback to HTTP if websockets are not supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the biggest disadvantage would be browser support. Websockets have great support in Chrome and Firefox but only recently came to Internet Explorer. By completely relying on websockets unless you had a fallback you'd be cutting off some older/mobile browsers.

Comment: There are solutions that have fallbacks for older browsers like [Socket IO](http://socket.io/) but it usually depends on what you are doing server-side.

Answer (score 0):

As kidshenlong already mentioned, the biggest problem would be browser support. You should also consider, though, that an open websocket uses up resources (mostly memory) on your server for *each* client that is currently connected.